# php array to csv download integrated into my current script not working properly

Tags: php, arrays, loops, download

I've found several useful and helpful tutorials and forum posts on this subject. But none I could find display an exact example and implementation of my current scenario.

I am trying to convert my completed query results array into csv format, so I can download the results, properly formatted, in .csv format.

Below is my code:

**This is my download action:**

```
<script>
    function getcsv(){
    window.location="script_4.php";
}
</script>
<input type="button" onclick="getcsv()" value="Download CSV">
```

**This is my while() loop merging my query data into a sequential numeric array:**

```
while ($row = mysql_fetch_row($result)) {
$industries = explode(",", $row[3]);
unset($row[3]);
$merge = array_merge($row, $industries);
echo "<pre>";
print_r($merge);
echo "</pre>";
}
```

**My print_r() above echoes out like this:**

```
Array
(
    [0] => 3561
    [1] => The Ace Company
    [2] => ace@not-a-real-site.com
    [3] => Waterproofing
)
Array
(
    [0] => 3562
    [1] => JOJO Associates, Inc.
    [2] => joj@not-a-real-site.com
    [3] => Lab Equipment & Casework
)
Array
(
    [0] => 3564
    [1] => Southern Style Pipe
    [2] => southern@no-a-real-site.com
    [3] => Plumbing
    [4] => Piping
    [5] => Pipe Inspection
)
```

**This is where I am at with the download script, and when I attempt it it loads my html and entire array into the csv with no csv formatting of array data.**

```
header("Content-type: text/csv");
header("Content-Disposition: attachment; filename=file.csv");
header("Pragma: no-cache");
header("Expires: 0");

outputCSV($merge);

function outputCSV($data) {
    $outstream = fopen("php://output", "w");
    function __outputCSV(&$vals, $key, $filehandler) {
        fputcsv($filehandler, $vals);
    }
    array_walk($data, "__outputCSV", $outstream);
    fclose($outstream);
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**I solved the problem like so:**

```
header("Content-type: text/csv");
header("Content-Disposition: attachment; filename=exhibitors-$date.csv");
header("Pragma: no-cache");
header("Expires: 0");
/////////////////////////////////////////////////////
/////////////////////////////////////////////////////
/////////////////////////////////////////////////////
// create a file pointer connected to the output stream
$output = fopen('php://output', 'w');
// output the column headings
fputcsv($output, array('ID', 'Company', 'Email', 'Address1', 'Address2', 'City',     'State', 'Province', 'Zip', 'Phone', 'Fax', 'Toll Free', 'Site'));
////////////////////////////////////////////////////
////////////////////////////////////////////////////
////////////////////////////////////////////////////
while ($row = mysql_fetch_row($result)) {
        $industries = explode(",", $row[13]);
        unset($row[13]);
    $merge = array_merge($row, $industries);
    fputcsv($output, $merge);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I think the comma (,) in the address fields causing issue, put a double quote around the strings so it can work

As we know CSV stands for comma separated values so it splits based on comma values, so the comma in strings like "**JOJO Associates, Inc.**" and it will be treated as two separate values. Adding double quote (") around it, so it treats as single values